# Is it possible to stop the googletrans module in python to survive a translation to French?

Tags: python, googletrans

When using the googletrans module in python and I attempt to translate a dictionary (with around 50-60 words) to specific languages including French I get this error:

`translated_parts = list(map(lambda part: TranslatedPart(part[0], part[1] if len(part) >= 2 else []), parsed[1][0][0][5]))`
This is the code I use to make my translations:

```
for key in translationsDb:
    for i, text in enumerate(translationsDb[key]):
        if lang != "en":
            transtext = translator.translate(translationsDb[key][i], dest = languages[lang.casefold()], src = "en")
            transDict[key][i] = transtext.text
        else:
            transDict[key][i] = text
```

Comment: I don('t see any error. Is it [this](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/260)?